# how to pack python packages and sub-packages as single package in python3

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, packaging, python-packaging

I'm trying to create a python package with below structure. when i'm trying to create the package **testproject** it is creating successfully and uploading successfully to https://test.pypi.org/legacy/

```
testproject/
    testproject/
        Core/
            __init__.py
            BaseModel.py
        lib/
            __init__.py
            RunModel.py
        __init__.py
        RunWorkflow.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
    setup.py
```

When i attempt to download it to my new environment it is downloading the correct version to my environment and when i run ***conda list*** i can see the installed package with correct version.

The actual problem is when i tried to run ***help('modules')*** command, it returns all the sub-packages [Core and lib] too. when i see other packages such as **os**, **numpy**, **scikit-learn**. it is not showing its sub-packages in ***help('modules')***.

how can i avoid this situation, am i doing anything wrong here ?

Please find my setup.py below.

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name='Test-Project-pypi',
    version='0.0.1',
    author="Manikandan Jeyabal",
    author_email="ManikandanJeyabal029@gmail.com",
    description="My longdestription",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires=[
        "numpy <=1.17.4", "pandas", "scikit-learn >= 0.21.3, <= 0.22"
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7'
 )
```

Comment: Show your `setup.py`. Or better yet the entire repository. In any case you publish your code at PyPI so why hide it here?

Comment: What do you see in the output of `help('modules')` that bothers you? Seems like you see `testproject.Core` and `testproject.lib`, is that really so?

Comment: Hi @phd i have attached my setup.py in the question please find it.

Comment: Hi @sinoroc, well exactly to describe my problem. i have Core package inside TestProject but without accessing TestProject i can access modules in Core like below.

it should be accessible like ```form testproject.Core.BaseModel import BaseModel``` but in my case i can access directly from ```Core.BaseModel import BaseModel```

Comment: It seems `Core` and `lib` became top-level packages. But I don't see how it's possible with this `setup.py`.

Comment: Maybe the current working directory is `testproject/testproject`. Or maybe the `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` have been altered.

Comment: Hi @phd, the issue god fixed by adding below answer. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Hi @sinoroc, the issue god fixed by adding below answer. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved by adding the below code in Main **init**.py under 'testproject'

```
from . import Core
from . import lib
```